# Cannot send both string and file as parameters to a web service simultaneously in Apache CXF + JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, file-upload, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to create a file upload web service which also needs a few string also to be passed as parameters as a small part of my project...

So far I have managed to create a file upload web-service. But it works only when I am passing only files to be uploaded as input. Now I modified the web-service to accept few parameters as well. But it is giving me error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: "&'"

I dint copy the entire stacktrace here I feel it would me pointless.
This is my web service :

```
    @POST 
@Path("/postdata") 
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void postData3(List<Attachment> atts, @FormParam("username") final String username, @Context HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println(username);
    String home = "/home/yashdosi/s";
    for(Attachment att : atts)
    {
        DataHandler dataHandler = att.getDataHandler();
        try 
        {
            InputStream stream = dataHandler.getInputStream();
            MultivaluedMap map = att.getHeaders();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(home + "//" + getFileName(map)));

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            stream.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Java Client :

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/fileupload-ws/services/postdata");

        FileBody img = new FileBody(new File("/home/yashdosi/1.jpg"));
        FileBody html = new FileBody(new File("/home/yashdosi/hotmail.html"));
        StringBody contentBody = new StringBody("some.email@gmail.com");

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("image", img);
        reqEntity.addPart("html", html);
        reqEntity.addPart("username", contentBody);

        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
        //httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        if (resEntity != null) {
            System.out.println("Response content length: " + resEntity.getContentLength());
        }
        EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try { httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown(); } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
```

Any ideas what is causing this error?
Or how I should get around this problem!?

Comment: Please indicate which line appears to be generating the error message. Is it a message that is seen in the server or the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `@MultiPart(value="image")` for image,  `@MultiPart(value="html")` for html and `@MultiPart(value="username")` for content body. Worked for me.